# Why is Toshiba SP S300 HD Error fixed by live Ubuntu boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, toshiba-laptop

**Machine:** Toshiba Satellite Pro S300 
**OS:** Ubuntu 13.04 (Also observed on 12.10) 
**Drive:** 128 GB Crucial SSD

After each crash (or upgrade), my Toshiba fails to boot citing an internal HDD error.
And subsequently performs a series of checks (Figure 1).
[image]

In order to fix this, I must use a live Ubuntu 13.04 USB and boot using the "Try Ubuntu" feature. Then, shutting down and removing the USB makes the system start up normally with no obvious issue. I do not yet understand how it is possible for a live OS boot to fix what seems like a hardware/firmware issue.

Any additional information will be added as edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a BIOS bug.

Visit your laptop manufacturer's website to get latest BIOS and an update utility (it will probably be available only for Windows). Be careful to choose the right update, even the differences of a single letter matter and flashing BIOS for different laptop model may break your machine.

Flashing isn't a complicated process. Make sure you have power adapter connected and your battery won't die during the procedure. Don't interrupt the process, close all other programs before starting it, especially stop any antivirus software and disconnect any network connections.

After flashing BIOS you'll have to reboot and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: At this point it is more of an intellectual curiosity than anything else. I would like to know how can a live boot fix (albeit temporarily) a BIOS bug?

Comment: Bugs usually don't make sense ;) Maybe there's some flag that is switched on every successful boot and prevents correct boot next time. There are thousands of possible reasons for this behavior.